# jQuery cycle pagerAnchorBuilder span in between li

Tags: jquery

I am creating a cycle slideshow, 
the problem is that, i have span in between li tags, 
the controller li buttons doesnt work fine as the actived li skipped the second menu button, if I get all span tags removed, it works good. 
any way I could keep span tags? 
how should I change "pagerAnchorBuilder" attr? 
THanks a lot in advance

here are codes

```
var $featured_content = $('#slide');
if ($featured_content.length) {
    $('#slide').cycle({ 
    activePagerClass: 'active',
    timeout: 0,         
    speed: 300,
    cleartypeNoBg: true,
    cleartype: true, 
    pager: '#controller ',
    fx: 'fade',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
           return '#controller li:eq(' + (idx) + ')';
        }
}); 
}






<ul id="controller">
<li>menu1</li>  
<span>|</span>
<li>menu2</li> 
<span>|</span>
<li>menu3</li>
<span>|</span>
<li>menu4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SPAN used like that is invalid. A UL's children should be nothing other than LIs.

You can achieve the same visual effect as `xxx | yyy | zzz` by styling the LIs with a combination of padding, border-left and border-right in your CSS. Presumably you are already using `display:inline`.

There must be many examples on the web, or it's quite simple to write for oneself.

Comment: thank you, but couldn't find one for subtract span space just leave li on there

Comment: "subtract span space"?? Are you saying that you don't have control of the source - ie. you can't prevent the spans from being included in the served page, and they have to be removed client-side?